# Group by in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do this query in BigQuery:

```sql
select email, format_date('%m %Y', min(booking_date)),              
CASE when  typology = 1 then 1 else 0 end as first_purchase_1,                 
CASE when typology = 0 then 1 else 0 end as first_purchase_0        
from `bookings`                                                    
group by email
```

But it gives me this error:

*SELECT list expression references column email which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:69]*

It makes me group by all non aggregated fields, which I don't want! I only want to group by email, not typology. I know in DBeaver it is possible to only group by one field, do you know if it is possible in BigQuery too ? Or how can I do it ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"I know in DBeaver (SQL platform)"* DBeaver isn't a SQL Platform, it's an IDE-like application

Comment: Can you add sample data, I assume across same email typology is same, right?

Comment: @pkd not necessarily, typology depends on the bookings and each email can have several bookings. The thing is if i do: `select email, typology, min(booking_date), phone, channel from bookings group by email` it won't let me do it, because I would also have to group by typology, phone and channel, and I only want to group by email...

Comment: If it's not same value, then let's say you have typology values as A,B for email E then when you group by email, which value for typology should come.?